# Erlang: is lots of timers ok?

Tags: timer, erlang, match

I have a gen_server process that maintains a pool, for each incoming request, I need to examining the pool to see if there is a match for this incoming request, if there is one, the matched one is removed from the pool and replies are made to both requests; if there is none, the new request is put to the pool for later examination.

The biz logic requires that, if a request, `R`, sits in the pool for `T` seconds without been matched, I need to make a reply to `R` saying something like "I cannot find a match for you".

Ideally, I want to do this with timers, specifically, for each incoming request, if there is no match, put it to the pool as before, but also start a timer to tell the gen_server to remove it if time is up, of course, if it is matched later, the timer should be cancelled.

My concern is that, If there are lots unmatched requests in the pool, then there would be lots of running timers, will this (too many timers) becomes a problem?

Comment: Not all timers work same way, I know `timer:start` is generally avoided and had performance penalty, while using `erlang:send_after` in thousands of processes seems common.

Comment: @Reith I'm using `erlang:send_after`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were done big improvements in timers implementation in [R18](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_18.0.readme).

> ```
>     Besides the API changes and time warp modes a lot of
>     scalability and performance improvements regarding time
>     management has been made internally in the runtime system.
>     Examples of such improvements are scheduler specific timer
>     wheels, scheduler specific BIF timer management, parallel
>     retrieval of monotonic time and system time on systems with
>     primitives that are not buggy.
> ```

*scheduler specific timer wheels* is exactly what is interesting in your scenario. I doubt you would come around better performant solution of your problem in Erlang or any other language/environment. So your solution should be OK when you are using R18 or newer.

Comment: At CodeMesh just a couple of days ago, Joe Armstrong demonstrated an example of spawning tens of thousands of processes, each sleeping a specific time and then playing a single MIDI note. Worked perfectly! :-)

Comment: Thanks, Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil. @RichardC I also started 10K timers myself to test, it doesn't even blink.